# mongoose throws internal server error when ID doesn't exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

mongoose `findOne` query throws `Interal Server Error (500)` when looking for a value that doesn't exists.
I'm pretty sure it should return `null` or empty array instead of throwing error.

**Mongoose version: ^5.8.7**

First attempt

```
router.get('/:myId', async(req, res, next) => {
  const myId = req.params.myId;
  
  await myDocument.findOne({ _id: myId }, (err, myData) => {
    if (!myData) {
      res.status(404).render('404');
    } else {
      res.render('myPage', myData);
    }
  }).exec()

});
```

second attempt

```
router.get('/:myId', async(req, res, next) => {
  const myId = req.params.myId;
  const myData = myDocument.findOne({_id: myId}).exec();
  
  if (myData) {
    //render normal page
  }
  // render 404 page
});
```

According to [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne), this should NOT happen.

> Note: conditions is optional, and if conditions is null or undefined, mongoose will send an empty findOne command to MongoDB, which will return an arbitrary document. If you're querying by _id, use findById() instead.

Also tried to use `findById()` and `find()`. All cases the same happens.
It works perfectly when I pass a valid ID parameter.
How to search for data without throwing http error in case Id doesn't exists in collection?

Answer (score 1):

```
router.get('/:myId', async(req, res, next) => {
```

You should check your route

Comment: I miss missed the parameter when writing here. The route is ok. sorry about it.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this code. First assign the ObjectId on top where are dependencies being called.
MongoDB id is not string. It is adviseble to pass the ObjectId.

```
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');
router.get('/:myId', async(req, res, next) => {
  const myId = ObjectId(req.params.myId);
  const myData = await myDocument.findOne({_id: myId}).exec();
  
  if (myData) {
    //render normal page
  }
  // render 404 page
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was actually happening during the page render.
In fact, `mongoose` does NOT throws any error in this case.

I was trying to render a `html` page while setting `ejs` as `View Engine`.
Apparentely we can't mix things.